# How do I change the background of the notification bubbles?

Tags: notify-osd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize on screen notifications in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Just installed 12.04 and it's great so far. I've noticed that the launcher background - and notification bubble - change colour according to the wallpaper I've selected.

How do I keep the wallpaper but change the notification background colour back to the transparent black? Right now, I have the blue-ish wallpaper set but don't like the blue notifications.

Comment: In terms of what doesn't work, I can't find any option in CCSM to make this happen. (The background color override isn't working consistently; I don't know why
.)