# How to customize on-screen notifications?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

There was a tool to configure notifications in earlier versions of Ubuntu as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html). I tried to install it in Ubuntu 12.04 too but I failed.

I want to have the notifications dynamically located (e.g. notifications for music player and volume control will be shown at the same place) and to reduce the notification duration.

How do I change settings of notifications?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

There is no official way of modifying the notifications, but many changes can be made to the notifications bubbles by installing a 3rd party patch which allows various changes to be made. More details are available here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html

**To install:**

Open a terminal window and enter these commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
pkill notify-osd
```

This installs a patched version of the notify-osd package. Then you will need to install the GUI configuration tool, to do this enter these commands one by one into a terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

To use the congfiguration tool type "notify" into the dash and launch the **NotifyOSD Configuration** application.

[image]

**Modifying the Notifications**

- From this application you can change the colour of the notifications
  by clicking on the **Background Colour** box (in the picture below
  I've turned it a horrible green!).
- To change the length of time the notifications appear on screen
  adjust the value in the **Timeout** box

[image]

The tool also includes other customisations including:

- Change font, opacity, size, corner radius
- Disable fade out
- Close the notifications on click
- Enable/disable "use Dash background colour for the notification
  bubbles"

**Changing the position**

To change the location that the notification appears you need to open a terminal and enter the following:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd gravity #
```

the # in the above code should be replaced by a number between 1-6 depending on where you want the notification to appear (3 doesn't seem to work for me though):

```
1 - top-right corner
2 - middle-right
3 - bottom-right corner
4 - bottom-left corner
5 - middle-left
6 - top-left corner
```

[image]

- In the **Position** drop down box you can choose from **Fixed** and
  **Dynamic**, dynamic gets rid of the gap between the notification bubble and the top dash

Comment: Bravo for this answer!!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The timeout box is enabled both on my machine and in your screenshot. Do you know how I can enable it?

Comment: It's important to note that the webupd8 PPA has many other packages in it, so it might be overwriting other packages...

Comment: A bit ridiculous that in 2014 you need to install a bunch of unofficial patches just to configure notifications, something that's a right click away on other OSes/desktop managers.

Comment: Only 2 works for me in the gsettings schema, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS :(

Comment: Is there a place to see the history of the notifications, in case wasn't looking at screen at the time of the notification?

Comment: Found something for the history: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history

Comment: Anyhow, only once the notification will provide some basic functionality, from opening the app that created them to doing actual stuff, it's a bit redundant :(

Comment: Unable to locate package notifyosdconfig

Comment: It's 2019 still waiting for an in-built way to do this.

Comment: wish they put this in the official Ubuntu repos

Comment: Unable to locate package notifyosdconfig

Comment: 2020 update to my 2014 comment: no progress. Whatsoever.

Answer (score 6):

I could not install `notifyosdconfig` using the PPA on my Ubuntu 15.04, but i got it working by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr libqt4-dev
bzr branch lp:notifyconf
cd notifyconf
make
./notifyosdconf
```

Which does not fully install it (you won't be able to find it in the dash) but it does work.

Comment: This tools provides the same options and does the same, but is a different one from `notifyosdconfig`. Looks a bit different, seems to be its Qt4 port. A bit more information is [here](https://launchpad.net/notifyconf).

Comment: Super Man , This is perfectly working in ubuntu 15.10 also...Thanks....

Comment: worked for ubuntu 17.10. Nice work

Comment: No such schema “com.canonical.notify-osd”
notify-osd: no process found

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone might come to this question sometime with a **Lubuntu** distro (or any other of the 'Buntu flavors), please note that things might be quite different there.
On Lubuntu, the best and quickest way is to use `xfce4-notifyd-config`; however, there is no way to have the notification dialog appear anywhere in the top center; merely the four corners are supported. But for those that don't need more, this will be sufficient by far to get the notification dialog out of the way when something else has been placed there and would constantly interfere resp. overlap.

Comment: Thanks for considering us Lubuntu users. After a year and a half, this answer deserves an upvote. BTW,  the last sentence with “resp. overlap” isn't very clear.

Comment: If your `xfce4-notifyd-config` settings do not have any effect, it could be because Ubuntu's `notify-osd` is also installed – then, it will show the notifications, not `xfce-notifyd`. To fix this: `sudo apt-get remove notify-osd` and `sudo killall notify-osd`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In my tool there are 3 Checkbox options at the end of **Bubble** tab which is not shown in previous answer's image, these options worked for me, I'll suggest U recheck the procedure of installation of this tool.

Comment: That was a year ago - 3/4 years ago Unity did not even exist - it probably just been updated.