# How can I change the location of the Ubuntu notifications?

Tags: 12.04, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize on screen notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications)

In Ubuntu 12.04, notifications appear at the left upper corner of the screen. Some times it's annoying me specially while working on Virtual Box. So, how to change the location of these notifications if I wanna for example make it appear on the left bottom corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to terminal `gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd gravity 4` this should move the notification to the  bottom-left corner you can read a more detailed answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/128508/71679