# How can I reset the notifications?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

After I installed a Xubuntu-session in addition to my existing Ubuntu-session, eveytime I login to the Ubuntu-session, the notify-bubbles appear with the Xubuntu-theme. Can I revert that somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this question:
[Unity Notifications do not look normal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251435/unity-notifications-do-not-look-normal)
Removing some Xfce packages (with the "purge" option)  worked for me.

If you *do* need the package `xfce4-notifyd` for some reason, you could try to modify OSD configuration as offered here: [How to customize on screen notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications).