# Unity Notifications do not look normal?

Tags: unity, 12.10, notification

Ok so I think this is because I am missing a package. My unity notifications (ex. when unity tells me it is connected to a network) look ugly. They used to be translucent chameleon rectangles. Now they are white and totally different. See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Think back a bit and recollect if you've installed a new theme or accidentally deleted something you shouldn't have. Have you rebooted? If you do provide additional information, please do so by editing your question.

Comment: That is what I have been trying to remember. Trouble is one of my friend got on my computer and screwed some stuff up. He uninstantiated system settings (gnome-control-center) which then caused me to lose indicator-power indicator-datetime gnome-control-center-signon and gnome-control-center-unity. I reinstalled them and every thing is back to normal but for this

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: yes I have rebooted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. I had xfce4-notifyd installed so a quick `sudo apt-get purge xfce4-notifyd` solved the problem.

Comment: I had to logout and log back in for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Define and add name extension suffix `.disable` to unwanted freedesktop daemons:

```
$ grep -r org.freedesktop.Notifications /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service.disable
pkill xfce4-notifyd
```

Sequently restart all notification using software.

Works just fine with **`mate`** issues also:

Replace **`xfce`** line to **`mate`**:

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.mate.Notifications.service.disable:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
```