# How can I resize the volume OSD in Gnome3 (Shell)?

Tags: gnome, gtk3

How can I resize the volume OSD display to a more "sane" size? Currently it takes about 1/4th of my screen height. I may be shortsighted, but not *that* shortsighted.

[image: Volume OSD]

I checked my theme settings, but couldn't find any hint for setting the size of this window. Where do I have to look?

Is it even a theme issue or is it gnome globally?

Comment: It's *probably* somewhere in /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css, but figuring out where is not easy.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find an extension, so I built one that let the user determine size, position and delay for the OSD window: 
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1345/better-osd/

Source code:
https://github.com/hajdbo/Better-OSD-GNOME-Extension/blob/master/README.md
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way of modifying the notifications, but many changes can be made to the notifications bubbles by installing a 3rd party patch which allows various changes to be made.

Using this method, I think you need to see this tutorial [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/128508/46312)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm not using Unity, therefore, notify-osd is also not running. From the comments of [http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html): "Gnome Shell has its own notification system and doesn't use notify-osd"