# plasma popup in Ubuntu

Tags: 10.10

I am looking for the source code for a plasma kind of popup and edit it to display my own messages.

[image]

This is the type of the popup i have been looking for. Can anyone suggest me some links. Thank you.

Comment: It's called NotifyOSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you're looking for is `notify-osd`.

**Installation:**

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install notify-osd
  ```

**Usage:**

You can run it using `notify-send`.

For example, to make a notification:

```
notify-send <message>
```

where `<message>` is the message you'd like in the notification.

So, if you write `notify-send "Hello World"`, the output would be something like

[image]

There are plenty of other options which you can read on the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/notify-send.1.html).

> **-u,  --urgency=LEVEL**  Specifies  the  urgency   level   (low, normal, critical).
>
> **-t, --expire-time=TIME**
>                 Specifies  the  timeout  in  milliseconds at which to expire the
>                 notification.
>
> **-i --icon=ICON[,ICON...]**
>                 Specifies an icon filename or stock icon to display.

***P.S.:*** If you'd like to modify the notifications, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications) is an answer that does just that.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what i needed. Thanks a ton.