# Don't bother non-admin users with admin questions

Tags: administration, permissions

My wife and kids use ubuntu laptops which I administer.

How do I prevent the system from, e.g., offering them software updates? (I know I can disable that for the whole box, but that is just one example of the wrong behavior - assuming that any user is an admin).

**Specifically, I want to mark some users as *non-admin users*, so that they are never prompted for anything which requires root password.**

I reported this as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1024178) but received no comments there. I wonder if I am barking up the wrong tree (i.e., the vast majority of ubuntu users administer their boxes). But what about all those ubuntu boxes in schools?

OTOH, the people affected by this issue, i.e., non-admin users, are unlikely to have a `launchpad` account, so they cannot vote for the bug.

Comment: I don't use either their updater or their notification daemon, but I can offer this:  what you want to do is to learn is whether notifications can be filtered according to certain criteria — which desktop workspace you view them on, which user or group has visibility.  I'm thinking something like Openbox or KWin allowing you to apply certain rules to new windows according to their titles or class.  I.E. this is nothing to do with the updater, but with [NotifyOSD](https://askubuntu.com/q/128474/).

Answer (score 0):

`Settings`-->`Session & Startup`-->take the check out of Update Notifier.

Comment: thank you, yes, this is precisely what I meant when I said "I know I can disable that for the whole box". My actual question is, however, marked in **bold**