# Ugly looking notifications in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, notification, notification-area

My notifications appear with this weird look.

[image: spotify song change notification]

What caused this?

```
$ uname -a      
Linux dev-pc 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ unity --version
unity 7.4.5

$ comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
curl
docker-ce
git
google-chrome-stable
i3
libbz2-dev
libncurses5-dev
libsqlite3-dev
libssl-dev
p7zip
python-setuptools
sublime-text
tixati
zlib1g-dev
zsh
```

Comment: Maybe this can help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications

Comment: i tried `sudo apt purge notify-osd` followed by `sudo apt install notify-osd`. Didnt work

Comment: Someone else suggested i remove the `xfce4-notifyd` package, but i  dont have that installed

Comment: Its actually a very fresh installation

Comment: Have you tried switching to another theme? Maybe also creating a dummy new user?

Comment: I have no theme, and i don't intend to mess with the default one. I will try that new user you say.
This problem isnt specific to spotify btw, also happens with network manager

Comment: I have added the list of manually- installed packages

Answer (score 0):

I ran `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, which installed some missing packages and after a reboot, it was restored to normal!